# c++ Decimal to binary, then use operation, then back to decimal

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have an array with x numbers: sets[  ](long numbers) and a char array operations[ ] with x-1 numbers. For each number from sets[ ], its binary form(in 64bits) would be the same as a set of numbers( these numbers being from 0 to 63 ), 1's and 0's representing whether it is inside a subset or not ( 1 2 4 would be 1 1 0 1, since 3 is missing)

ex: decimal 5 --->000...00101 , meaning that this subset will only have those 2 last numbers inside it(#63 and #61)

now,using the chars i get in operations[], i should work with them and the binaries of these numbers as if they were operations on subsets(i hope subset is the right word), these operations being :

U = reunion ---> 101 U 010 = 111

A = intersection ---> 101 A 001 = 001

\ =   A - B      ---> 1110 - 0011 = 1100

/ =   B-A   ---> like the previous one

so basically I'd have to read numbers, make them binary, use them as if they were sets and use operations accordingly, then return the result of all these operations on them.

my code :

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void makeBinaryVector(int vec[64], long xx)  
{

// put xx in binary form in array "vec[]"
int k = 63;
long x = xx;

if(xx == 0)
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
        vec[i] = 0;


while(x != 0)
{
    vec[k] = x % 2;
    x = x / 2;
    k--;
}
}

void OperationInA(int A[64], char op, int B[64])
{
int i;
if(op == 'U')           //reunion
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)      
        if(B[i] == 1)
            A[i] = 1;

if(op == 'A')           //intersection
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        if((B[i] == 1) && (A[i] == 1))
            A[i] = 1;
        else
            A[i] = 0;
    }

if(op == '\\')          //A-B
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)   
    {
        if( (A[i] == 0 && B[i] == 0) || (A[i] == 0 && B[i] == 1) )
            A[i] = 0;
        else

            if((A[i] == 1) && (B[i] == 1))
                A[i] = 0;
            else
                if((A[i] == 1) && (B[i] == 0))
                    A[i] = 1;
    }

if(op == '/')           //B-A
    for(i=0;i<64;i++)   
    {
        if(B[i] == 0)
            A[i] = 0;
        else

            if((B[i] == 1) && (A[i] == 0))
                A[i] = 1;
            else
                if((B[i] == 1) && (A[i] == 1))
                    A[i] = 0;
    }

}


unsigned long setOperations(long sets[], char operations[], unsigned int x)
{

unsigned int i = 1;     //not 0, since i'll be reading the 1st number separately
unsigned int j = 0;
unsigned int n = x;
int t;
long a = sets[0];
int A[64];              
for(t=0;t<64;t++)
    A[t] = 0;

makeBinaryVector(A, a);  //hold in A the first number, binary, and the results of operations
long b;
int B[64];
for(t=0;t<64;t++)      //Hold the next number in B[], in binary form
    B[t] = 0;

char op;

while(i < x && j < (x-1) )
{
    b = sets[i];

    makeBinaryVector(B, b);

    op = operations[j];

    OperationInA(A, op, B);

    i++; j++;
}

        //make array A a decimal number

unsigned int base = 1;
long nr = 0;
for(t=63; t>=0; t--)
{
    nr = nr + A[t] * base;
    base = base * 2;
}

return nr;
}

long sets[100];
char operations[100];
long n,i;

int main()
{


cin>>n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>sets[i];

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    cin>>operations[i];

cout<<setOperations(sets,operations,n);

return 0;

}
```

So everything seems fine, except when im trying this :

sets = {5, 2, 1}
operations = {'U' , '\'}

5 U 2 is 7(111), and 7 \ 1  is 6 (111 - 001 = 110 --> 6)
the result should be 6, however when i Input them like that the result is 4 (??)

however, if i simply input {7,1} and { \ } the result is 6,as it should be. but if i input them like i first mentioned {5,2,1} and {U,} then its gonna output 4.

I can't seem to understand or see what im doing wrong...

Comment: Please avoid tagging C and C++ at the same time unless you want to compare/use both of them

Comment: There are so many questions these days with the message at end "I can't seem to understand where I went wrong"

Comment: Just use cout or printf inside and outside of every loop with appropriate messages and find the logical error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to "convert to binary numbers".
There's no such thing as 'binary numbers'. You can just perform the operations on the variables.

For the *reunion*, you can use the bitwise *OR* operator '|', and for the intersection, you can use the bitwise *AND* operator '&'.

Something like this:

```
if (op == 'A')
    result = a & b;
else if (op == 'U')
    result = a | b;
else if (op == '\\')
    result = a - b;
else if (op == '/')
    result = b - a;
```

Comment: Thank you !
For some reason, i thought i should be solving it precisely as in their example(with numbers between 0 and 63 and check them with subset / bit operations) . Guess you could say i "forgot to think" ... Thankyou for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use bitwise operators on integers as shown in @Hugal31's answer.

Note that integer size is usually 32bit, not 64bit. On a 64bit system you need `long long` for 64bit integer. Use `sizeof` operator to check. `int` is 4 bytes (32bit) and `long long` is 8 bytes (64bit).

For the purpose of homework etc., your conversion to vector cannot be right. You should test it to see if it outputs the correct result. Otherwise use this:

```
void makebinary(int vec[32], int x)
{
    int bitmask = 1;
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        vec[i] = (x & bitmask) ? 1 : 0;
        bitmask <<= 1;
    }
}
```

Note the use of shift operators. To AND the numbers you can do something like the following:

```
int vx[32];
int vy[32];
makebinary(vx, x);
makebinary(vy, y);

int result = 0;
int j = 1;
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int n = (vx[i] & vy[i]) ? 1 : 0;
    result += n * j;
    j <<= 1;
}
```

This is of course pointless because you can just say `int result = X & Y;`

Comment: Thankyou! yes, 

I know i should be using an array of 32, specially since the entire function is LONG, but since text explicitly says representative to numbers between [0 , 63] , i thought i'd have to comply. Don't know how their evaluator might act,or if it'd check only the Output or the entire code.

Thakyou again for your replies